# Analytic metric on Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, analyticity

What is meant for a metric being analytic on a Riemannian manifold?

I am looking for the definition, and if you could write some bibliography where I can read about analyticity on riemannian metrics will be awesome.

Comment: It means that in an analytic chart, the coefficients of the metric are analytic.

Comment: But is possible to define analicity for functions defined on manifolds (or open sets on the manifolds)?

Comment: Yes, for an analytic manifold, for which the charts are analytic (that is so are the change of charts). The same way a complex manifold has complex charts, an affine manifold affine charts, etc.